# MongoDB not using available memory

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am experimenting with using MongoDB for handling an extremely large data set that I would like to be able to perform queries on and I have run into an issue that seems like a configuration issue but I can't seem to figure it out.

**The Setup**

I currently have 4 machines in my cluster and they all have the same specs (2 x 8-Core Xeon E5-2667 @ 3.5Ghz, 512Gb of Ram, 100Gb/s Infiniband network). I am using 1 machine as my "client" and the other three as the mongodb cluster. I am using the mongodb docker container on all of the cluster machines. One possible issue is the fact that there is no locally attached storage on the machines, all of their storage is provided via Ceph over the 100Gb/s Infiniband.

I cheated somewhat and put the router and config server on the same machine as the first mongodb node, the other two machines just have the mongodb node. Because the data is already replicated via Ceph I chose to shard the database and set each node up as a shard with a replicate set each only having 1 machine. (Perhaps this is part of my problem but it made sense to me)

I should also mention that all of my queries/inserts are done from the client using pymongo.

**The Data**

The data set I have is a bunch of time series data, there is no relations at all in the data so it seems ideal for a no-sql type db. I am only trying to insert a portion of the data, about 550 data-points per time step and about 600 million time steps. I sharded the database on a field that segments the data into about 86,000 segments so I felt that was a good choice.

I had no trouble inserting the data, the database was not the bottleneck, the limiting factor was how fast my client was able to processes the existing data files (they are currently in csvs).

**The Issue**

Once I inserted all the documents, the database size was around 1.4TB. Between the 3 nodes I have 1.5TB of memory but with overhead, docker containers, etc. I did not expect the whole dataset to fit in memory but it should have been close. However, when I go and look at the nodes, each one is only using somewhere between 100GB and 150GB of memory. So that seems wrong to me, I thought mongo would put as much of the database in memory. I have set no resource limits on mongo or on docker.

If I query an indexed field I get a very quick response which is to be expected, to start I only indexed the field that I sharded on. I later added another index which took a while to add not sure how long I let it run for the weekend.

If I do any query that touches a non-indexed field it takes forever, I have let it run overnight and still no results.

What I find strange is that when I look at the mongo nodes, only one core is working, maybe at around 50% load, the memory is still sitting mostly empty, and the network is barely being used (~10Mbps which leads me to believe that Ceph isn't the bottleneck).

So I could add more nodes but it doesn't seem like the hardware is the bottleneck at this point. Furthermore, I don't even know what a reasonable query time should be on something like this, seconds, minutes, hours? I feel like if most of the data is in memory is shouldn't take hours.

I just feel like I'm missing something so I thought I would reach out and see if it was something obvious or if I'm just expecting too much or the wrong things. Thanks for any help you can give, I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit:
Here is the docker compose files I use for each of the nodes.

Node 1:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongosn1:
    container_name: mongosn1
    image: mongo
    hostname: snode1
    extra_hosts:
      - "snode1:10.0.2.107"
      - "snode2:10.0.2.108"
      - "snode3:10.0.2.109"
      - "cfgnode1:10.0.2.107"
      - "rtnode1:10.0.2.107"
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet mongors1 --dbpath /data/db --port 27019 --smallfiles
    ports:
      - "27019:27019"
    expose:
      - "27019"
    volumes:
      - /mnt/work/db/mongo/data/shard1:/data/db
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  mongocfg1:
    container_name: mongocfg1
    image: mongo
    hostname: cfgnode1
    extra_hosts:
      - "snode1:10.0.2.107"
      - "snode2:10.0.2.108"
      - "snode3:10.0.2.109"
      - "cfgnode1:10.0.2.107"
      - "rtnode1:10.0.2.107"
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet mongors1conf --dbpath /data/db -- port 27018 --smallfiles
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
    expose:
      - "27018"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /mnt/work/db/mongo/data/config1:/data/db  
  mongort1:
    container_name: mongort1
    image: mongo    
    hostname: rtnode1
    depends_on:
      - mongocfg1
    extra_hosts:
      - "snode1:10.0.2.107"
      - "snode2:10.0.2.108"
      - "snode3:10.0.2.109"
      - "cfgnode1:10.0.2.107"
      - "rtnode1:10.0.2.107"
    command: mongos --configdb mongors1conf/cfgnode1:27018 --port 27017 -- bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

Node 2:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongosn1:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    hostname: snode2
    extra_hosts:
      - "snode1:10.0.2.107"
      - "snode2:10.0.2.108"
      - "snode3:10.0.2.109"
      - "cfgnode1:10.0.2.107"
      - "rtnode1:10.0.2.107"
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet mongors2 --dbpath /data/db --port 27017 --smallfiles
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /mnt/work/db/mongo/data/shard2:/data/db
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

Node 3:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongosn1:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    hostname: snode3
    extra_hosts:
      - "snode1:10.0.2.107"
      - "snode2:10.0.2.108"
      - "snode3:10.0.2.109"
      - "cfgnode1:10.0.2.107"
      - "rtnode1:10.0.2.107"
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet mongors3 --dbpath /data/db --port 27017 --smallfiles
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /mnt/work/db/mongo/data/shard3:/data/db
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

Comment: Can you put your mongod.conf in the issue? And with witch commands do you start MongoDB?

Comment: @StuiterSlurf I put my docker compose files in the original post, I haven't made a mongod.conf file so I assume it uses the default. When I log into the mongo docker instance it doesn't have one in /etc/

Comment: I think you just need to create a config file. With that file you can set how much your instance can use all the time. Now you say you don't got a configuration but Mongo can't run without one as far as I know. By the way, questions like these I always ask on superuser in stead of stackoverflow :-)

Comment: @StuiterSlurf From what I understand if mongo isn't provided a config file it will just use the defaults. I looked through the config options and the only setting that stood out to me was "storage.inMemory.engineConfig.inMemorySizeGB" but it says that is only for mongodb enterprise. I will post to superuser as well and see if I get a response there. Thanks for your help.